# Qt/C++ - Convert QHostAddress to QString

Tags: c++, qt

How can I convert `QHostAddress` to `QString` in IPv4 format ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`QHostAddress::toString()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhostaddress.html#toString).

**Update**

If you have a `QHostAddress` instance that encapsulates an IPv6 address (that is, `QHostAddress::protocol()` returns `QAbstractSocket::IPv6Protocol`), you must first convert the address to the IPv4 address and then convert the IPv4 address to a `QString`:

```
QHostAddress ip6Address;
bool conversionOK = false;
QHostAddress ip4Address(ip6Address.toIPv4Address(&conversionOK));
QString ip4String;
if (conversionOK)
{
    ip4String = ip4Address.toString();
}
```

It's also worth noting that the above IP6 to IP4 conversion **will not work** for Qt 4.  It will only work for Qt 5.

Comment: in qt5 by default it returns "::ffff:192.168.1.1" =(

Comment: it works

p.s. I would just add check opportunity of transformation:
`bool ok = false;
ip6Address.toIPv4Address(&ok);
`if (ok)
   ...`